# How to calculate z-score between two variable if their z-score with a third variable are known?

Tags: regression, z-score

Suppose I have three variables (x, y, z) and I am calculating their regression coefficients.

How to calculate Z-score between two variable (Z-score_xy) if Z-scores of two variable with a third variable are known (Z-score_xz, Z-score_yz)?

If you can show the calculation with beta would also be helpful.

Give reference please.